# JSPDF and html2canvas with Angular

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to generate a PDF with html2canvas but when calling the function I throw an error, my TS is the following:

```
  @ViewChild('content') content:ElementRef;

  generarPDF() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('content'), {
      // Opciones
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: false,
      // Calidad del PDF
      scale: 1
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.addImage(img,'PNG',7, 20, 195, 105);
      doc.save('postres.pdf');
    });
  }
```

My html is:

```css
div.cliente {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

div.fecha {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted;
    width: 28%;
    float: right;
}

ul.satisfacion {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

```html
  <div #content id="content">
    <div class="contenido-pdf">
     
      <div class="cliente">
        <span>Cliente: </span>
        <div class="campo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fecha">
          <span>Fecha: </span>
          <div class="campo"></div>
        </div>
      <ul class="satisfacion">
        <li>El servicio es muy satisfactorio</li>
        <li>El servicio es satisfactorio</li>
        <li>El servico es normal</li>
        <li>El servicio no es satisfactorio</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="generarPDF()" id="donwloadpdf">
  DESCARGAR CARTA DE CONFORMIDAD
</button>
```

And my error

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData 
e.convertStringToImageData
```

When I am going to click on generate pdf it does not generate it or do anything, it just throws that error on my console, I already tried to generate it with jsPDF but the problem is that it does not preserve the styles

Comment: What version of jspdf and html2canvas are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your css is doing something weird and making the div with `id="content"` have no content.

You can see this if you put

```
#content {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

I've commented out your css and produced the following [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so57240645-pdf)

Uncomment the css to see the issue.

**Steps to reproduce stackblitz**

*angular.json*

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js",
  "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"
]
```

*dependancies*

1. I've avoided an issue with html2canvas by using `html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.1`. see -
   https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1896
2. The latest version of jspdf is not working with some issue with file-saver so I've just gone for the version I know works `jspdf@1.4.1`
3. Include types `@types/html2canvas`, `@types/jspdf`
4. For some reason in stackblitz you need to import these using

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

 @ViewChild('content', { 'static': true }) content:ElementRef;

  generarPDF() {

    const div = document.getElementById('content');
    const options = {
      background: 'white',
      scale: 3
    };

    html2canvas(div, options).then((canvas) => {

      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG");
      var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4', 1);

      // Add image Canvas to PDF
      const bufferX = 5;
      const bufferY = 5;
      const imgProps = (<any>doc).getImageProperties(img);
      const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 * bufferX;
      const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
      doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, undefined, 'FAST');

      return doc;
    }).then((doc) => {
      doc.save('postres.pdf');  
    });
  }

}
```

***It anyone comes across a way to improve this answer feel free to just edit it, I'll accept any such edits.***

**Update - Improved using** [Pdf file size too big created using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677750)

Comment: thanx @Andrew but I need give styles to my PDF

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín that's fine, nothing's stopping you except don't give styles that makes the div with `id=content` have a zero area, which yours currently does. Your `float` css seems to cause this - see my updated stackblitz

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín note that specifically dotted/dashed border is an open issue with html2canvas https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/1146