# Save some space with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, jspdf

I use jsPDF to make PDFs using svg2pdf. I have lots of pages, and each page has the same background content (images text paths etc).

The images in particular account for a huge amount of the file size. Because all my images are base64 encoded, svg2pdf always makes a new entry for the same image on each page. I want my images (or all items for that matter) to be added to the File Stream once and then referenced on each page.

Is there a way I could modify svg2pdf (which was really made for single page PDFs but I have got it to work for multiple pages) or jsPDF to add this feature?

Related: [Pdf file size too big created using jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677750/pdf-file-size-too-big-created-using-jspdf)

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the files in the library and go there with image? 
Maybe I didn't understand the question, if so, please.

Comment: Please only post an answer if you can provide a definitive answer. Otherwise please use the comments. Thanks.